# Move Data from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, data-migration

I would like to copy parts of an Oracle DB to a SQL Server DB.  I need to move the data because the Oracle box is being decommissioned.  I only need the data for reference purposes so don't need indexes or stored procedures or contstaints, etc.  All I need is the data.

I have a link to the Oracle DB in SQL Server.  I have tested the following query, which seemed to work just fine:

select
  * 
into
  NewTableName
from 
  linkedserver.OracleTable

I was wondering if there are any potential issues with using this approach?

Comment: Any idea of data volumes?
I've done exactly the same without issues. Worked really well.

Answer (score 3):

Using SSIS (sql integration services) may be a good alternative especially if your table names are the same on both servers.  Use the import wizard via and it should create the destination tables for you and let you edit any mappings.

Comment: +1 SSIS solution worked easily for me - there is no need for overhead like DB links, just two connections - you specify the imported data via an SQL query statement, and that's it, more or less. In practice it was a bit tricky to come to SSIS as an option at all - the SSIS script file is created during SQL Server Management Studio Import/Export, if you check the corresponding option, and then you have to do somewhat manual changes to it, before executing.. - then, i didn't need to "MOVE" data - but SSIS appears to offer quite a lot for customizable tasks, so it's worth a try..

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I see with that is you will need to execute that of course for each and every table you need.  Glad you are decommissioning the oracle server :-).  Otherwise if you are not concerned with indexes or any of the existing sprocs I don't see any issue in what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The "select " approach could be very slow if tables are large. Consider writing pro*C in that case or use Fastreader http://www.wisdomforce.com/products-FastReader.html

Answer (score 0):

A faster and easier approach might be to use the Data Transformation Services, depending on the number of objects you're trying to copy over.